# How to set up a JavaScript Event Handler for a Primefaces TabView

Tags: javascript, primefaces, tabview

I am using the Primefaces TabView component.  I am trying to set up a JavaScript Event Handler to be called when a tab is clicked.  What I want to do, on the client, is to update the contents of the tab using JavaScript.  I don't want to do it through JSF or on the Server.  Basically, I am trying to update an IFrame using JavaScript only when a Tab is clicked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

may be this stuff will solve your problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("a[href='#tab1']").click(function(){
           alert('tab1');
       });
jQuery("a[href='#tab2']").click(function(){
           alert('tab2');
});
</script>
```

tab1 & tab2 are tab Id

Comment: Thanks! The "tabs" don't really exist, I finally had to add the click function to the anchor tag.

Comment: @Chaos Rules if this answer work done, please mark the answer as answered question :)